# Can I use guards to chef if a windows service is running?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm writing a chef recipe and on this I need to perform an operation (run a batch) only if a service is not working.
I use this snippet:

```
batch 'run commnad' do
  cwd target_path + '/bin/win64'
    code 'command to be executed'
    not_if '::Win32::Service.exists?("Service name")'
end
```

But it does not seems to work. After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131754/chef-how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-service-is-installed) question I changed the process using an if clause instead of the guard and it works fine:

```
if !::Win32::Service.exists?("Service name") then
  batch 'Install zabbix agent' do
    cwd target_path + '/bin/win64'
    code 'command to be executed'
  end
end
```

But this should not be, for what I understood, the right way to manage this, so I'm wondering: why is the guard not working properly?

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you wrote your `not_if` statement runs the command as a shell script.
The shell doesn't know Ruby code, so the whole command will fail.
Need to first:

`require win32/service`

In order to use `not_if` with Ruby code you should put it inside a block instead:

```
not_if { ::Win32::Service.exists?("Service name") }
```

See some more examples here (search for `not_if` on the page):
https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html

Comment: The { } solved the problem. I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to do it more Ruby-ish you could also append a conditional to the batch resource call, i.e.

`batch 'run command' do
...
end unless <logic for disabled service>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example (Chef 13)

```
   require 'win32/service'
   windows_service "jenkins" do
      action [:stop, :disable]
      only_if { ::Win32::Service.exists?("jenkins")}
   end
```